# Apache Access/Error Logs Not Populated in Docker Container with Supervisor D

Tags: php, apache, docker, supervisord

I am running Apache 2.4.7 in an Ubuntu container and the Apache access/error logs are not being populated. Here is the Dockefile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER me@mysite.com

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2 supervisor php5 php5-mysql php5-cli

RUN mkdir -p /var/lock/apache2 /var/run/apache2 /var/log/supervisor

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod ssl
RUN a2enmod headers

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY pickle /etc/logrotate.d/pickle
COPY pickle_socket /etc/logrotate.d/pickle_socket
COPY pickleudp /etc/logrotate.d/pickleudp

ADD 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
ADD default-ssl.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
ADD apache2.conf /etc/apache2/
ADD www-server/ /www-server/

EXPOSE 80 443 

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

The SupervidorD config file. Other services are started here, but are not relevant:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:apache2]
command=/bin/bash -c "source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND"
```

Finally here is the 000-default.conf for Apache setting up and writing to the log files:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /www-server/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<Directory /www-server/>
    # prevent potential clickjacking
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    # allow .htaccess overrides to work
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex login.html index.html index.php
</Directory>
```

I have confirmed the appropriate directive has been set in /etc/apache2/envvars - `export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX`

After much research, reading bug reports, etc. I am no closer to solving the issue than when I started. Am I doing something incorrectly to get the log files to populate? Or is there something I must be aware of when running Apache in a Docker container?

Comment: Can you, just for test, configure error log as `ErrorLog /tmp/error.log` and check if it gets created?

Comment: Did you check to make sure `/var/log/apache2...` exists? On somewhat related note, are you using a volume to store the log files? You might be better off having Docker manage the logs via syslog driver or similar.

Comment: Yes, the directory exists @ldg. The log files will be rotated daily, so I wasn't planning to use a volume for storage.

Comment: @DusanBajic Yes - if I configure the error log to be in `/tmp/` and restart Apache in the container the file gets created.

Comment: Perhaps try `ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log` next (to confirm if it is permission issue)?

Comment: I did that and still no joy @DusanBajic

Comment: @JayBlanchard if the log path exists and has the correct permissions, it's still not the best idea to write files to running container, especially log files due to the way the native docker filesystem works. You still are going to be better off writing to a volume or stdout, stderr or a Docker log driver. (I find syslog to work very well. It aggregates all the logs -- good for clusters -- and then I can manage them with Logstash.)

Comment: I understand @ldg, but in the short term while we're testing it would be handy to have this working.

Comment: and also perhaps try it out with an "official" Apache httpd Docker image as a base and see how that goes. You'll lose supervisord, but that can be problematic anyway.

Comment: Until we can refactor I can't drop SupervisorD. We've never seen it to be problematic.

Comment: Can you check what is the owner:group of the file `/tmp/error.log` and the same for the folder `/var/log/apache2`?

Comment: The owner is the same, the group is different @DusanBajic

Comment: @JayBlanchard, any chance you have AppArmor running? If so - you have to configure it for apache. You can try `sudo apparmor_status`

Comment: No @Dekel, I don't have that running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I have located the access/error logs *inside the Docker container* under `/var/log/supervisor/` which, [according to Supervisor's docs](http://supervisord.org/logging.html#child-process-logs), is the typical location for all such child-process logs:

> The stdout of child processes spawned by supervisor, by default, is captured for redisplay to users of supervisorctl and other clients. If no specific logfile-related configuration is performed in a [program:x], [fcgi-program:x], or [eventlistener:x] section in the configuration file, the following is true:
>
> - supervisord will capture the child process’ `stdout` and `stderr` output into temporary files. Each stream is captured to a separate file. This is known as AUTO log mode.
> - AUTO log files are named automatically and placed in the directory configured as childlogdir of the supervisord section of the config file.
>     -The size of each AUTO log file is bounded by the `{streamname}_logfile_maxbytes` value of the program section (where `{streamname}` is “stdout” or “stderr”). When it reaches that number, it is rotated (like the activity log), based on the `{streamname}_logfile_backups`.